# Catch the parameters from url in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I'm beginners and learning the tutorials from the tutorial point website 
here is the link.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_controllers.htm
I'm following its instruction to create a controller and catch the parameter from the url but it is showing problem sometime it shows the blank page when i run and sometime it shows the error.

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /employee/

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0.

Here is my controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCControllerDemo.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee


        public ActionResult Search(string name)
        {
            var input = Server.HtmlEncode(name);
            return Content(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the routeConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Welcome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
   "Employee", "Employee/{name}", new
   {
       controller = "Employee", action = "Search", name =UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the special route before the default.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Employee",
    url: "Employee/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Welcome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Controller and Action names in a MapRoute are case sensitive.

As such, Employee and employee do not match. You either want to change the incoming URL or adjust your controller setup to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "employee", "employee/{name}", new
   {
       controller = "Employee", action = "Search", name =UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
```